# express not sending static directory

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

I'm trying to serve a vue.js single page app with a node.js server but I'm having an issue with some express middleware.

Basically I'm trying to serve two things right now. My index.html and a dist folder that holds all of my static files. On `localhost` my `index.html` is served correctly but I'm getting a GET error for my dist folder and can not find it in the sources tab.

I've used more or less this same line of code for many single page apps before to serve my static assets but for some reason with this set up it's not serving the dist folder.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
```

Anyone with express experience know why this line isn't working?

Comment: can you show the path for the http error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `express.static` incorrectly. By default, `express.static` will serve the content you have INSIDE of that `dist` folder.

What you want to do is this:

```
app.use('/dist', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
```

This will force express to serve those static assets under the `'/dist'` route.